Plotly (Javascript) : fix the rotation point
I'm using Pltly with Javascript and I try to force the rotation point of the camera but the results are not as expected.
Here is my CodePen
https://codepen.io/someuser12/pen/rNXLPRJ
And here is my code
sphereData = this.generateSphere(50, 20, 0, 0, 0);
sphereData2 = this.generateSphere(50, 20, 1000, 0, 0);
var data = [
  {
    x: sphereData.x,
    y: sphereData.y,
    z: sphereData.z,
    mode: "markers",
    type: "surface",
    colorscale: [
      [0, "rgb(0, 255, 0)"],
      [1, "rgb(0, 255, 0)"]
    ],
    showscale: false,
    hovertemplate: "<extra></extra>",
    opacity: 0.2
  },
  {
    x: sphereData2.x,
    y: sphereData2.y,
    z: sphereData2.z,
    mode: "markers",
    type: "surface",
    colorscale: [
      [0, "rgb(0, 255, 0)"],
      [1, "rgb(0, 255, 0)"]
    ],
    showscale: false,
    hovertemplate: "<extra></extra>",
    opacity: 0.2
  }
];

var layout = {
  title: "Center rotation point",
  width: 1280,
  height: 480,
  autosize: true,
  scene: {
    aspectmode: "data",
    camera: {
      eye: { x: 1.5, y: -1.5, z: 1.5 },
      center: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 },
      up: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }
    }
  }
};
Plotly.newPlot("myDiv", data, layout);

function changeCenter(x) {
  console.log("ici");
  var myPlot = document.getElementById("myDiv");
  var update = {
    "scene.camera": {
      center: { x: x, y: 0, z: 0 }
    }
  };
  Plotly.relayout("myDiv", update);
}

function generateSphere(radius, resolution, centerX, centerY, centerZ) {
  const x = [];
  const y = [];
  const z = [];

  for (let i = 0; i <= resolution; i++) {
    const theta = (i * Math.PI) / resolution; // angle azimutal
    const sinTheta = Math.sin(theta);
    const cosTheta = Math.cos(theta);

    const rowX = [];
    const rowY = [];
    const rowZ = [];

    for (let j = 0; j <= resolution; j++) {
      const phi = (j * 2 * Math.PI) / resolution; 
      const sinPhi = Math.sin(phi);
      const cosPhi = Math.cos(phi);

      rowX.push(centerX + radius * sinTheta * cosPhi);
      rowY.push(centerY + radius * sinTheta * sinPhi);
      rowZ.push(centerZ + radius * cosTheta);
    }

    x.push(rowX);
    y.push(rowY);
    z.push(rowZ);
  }

  return { x, y, z };
}


I don't understand why when i specify the rotation center to x=1000, the graph disappear and does't fix the rotation point to the second sphere (located in 1000,0,0).
And why when the graph is created, the rotation center is not at 0,0,0 as specified in the layout.
The idea is on the more complex 3D graph with various sphere, just click on the sphere to fix to rotation center to this sphere and then allow to user to rotate around this sphere.
Thank you for your help.
